# How to use borderRadius and borderLeftColor, borderBottomColor, borderRightColor, borderTopColor in CSS?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want the circle with 25% coloured border and 75% transparent but got as unexpected 100% circle border with black colour.

I also tried borderRadius for each corner but it's not giving desirable output.

progressLayer: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
     borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopColor: '#3498db',
    borderRadius: 100,
  }
});

circle with 25% colored border and 75% transparent.

Comment: I don't think you are able to make a border transparant. You are able to set overall transparancy of the object through the `opacity` property. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.6/view-style-props#opacity

Answer (score 1):

To make some borders transparent, this should work:

`border-right: 2px solid transparent;`

And same for other borders.

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick for using transparent instead of opacity is to use rgba colors, so , it would´t be `borderLeftColor: 'transparent'` , instead use `borderLeftColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'`
[the last 0 is the transparency, if you use 0,0,0,1 it will be black and 0,0,0,0.5 gives a nice black overlay].

**Another solution**
Is just enable borderwidth for an specific direction.

```
progressLayer: { width: 200, height: 200, borderTopWidth: 20, position: 'absolute', borderTopColor: '#3498db', borderRadius: 100, } });
```

should work but not tested for a circle